# Problemas ao usar GraphAPI no Python - "não existe o atributo GraphAPI no Modulo Facebook"?

Tags: python, facebook

Olá, então, como sugere o titulo, estou tentando usar a graphAPI do facebook mas sem sucesso, meu objetivo é fazer mineração de dados pra ciencia de dados, mas não to tendo muito sucesso, estou seguindo a documentação e tudo mais, só que fico encontrando esse erro:

```
`AttributeError: partially initialized module 'facebook' has no attribute 'GraphAPI' (most likely due to a circular import)`
```

O código em questão é esse:

**facebook.py**

```
   import os
   import dotenv
   import facebook
   import urllib3
   
   dotenv.load_dotenv()
   
   token = os.environ['USER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
   
   graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version=8.0)
   events = graph.request('/search?q=Teste&type=event&limit=10000')
```

Eu tive meu primeiro contato com a GraphAPI hoje mesmo,  só que ai cheguei nisso ai e não acho nada no google, tudo aponta pro mesmo caminho, ai não sei se é algo que fiz de errado no projeto como um todo, ou deixei de instalar algum requerimento.

E por ultimo, as chaves de acesso estão corretas(pelo menos até onde eu sei).

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Por acaso o nome do seu arquivo é facebook.py? Se for, renomea-lo deve resolver o problema, pois neste caso o interpretador do Python estaria procurando por GraphAPI dentro do seu arquivo. No mais, tente descrever qual é o "mesmo caminho" que foi apontado em suas pesquisas e você tentou como solução. Saber o que você já tentou facilita na resolução do problema.

Comment: era o nome mesmo, obrigado! Quanto a parte do "mesmo caminho" eu queria dizer de como fazia a parte do GraphAPI, mas de qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o seu script tem o nome de `facebook.py' e acontece pela maneira em que a importação de módulos funciona no Python.

Quando escrevemos  `import foo` ou `from foo import bar`, o Python irá buscar pelo módulo `foo` nos seguintes lugares:

1. Módulo embutidos.
2. O diretório em que o script está sendo executado.
3. `PYTHONPATH`, semelhante a variável `$PATH`, contém uma lista de diretórios.
4. Diretórios padrão (dependem da instalção)

No caso da pergunta do tópico, nomear o script como `facebook.py` faz com que o Python procure por `GraphAPI` no script `facebook.py`. Renomear este arquivo para um nome diferente, fará com que o Pyhton importe corretamente o módulo `facebook`, que será encontrado em algum dos diretórios listados em `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Foi falta de atenção por minha parte. Agora já está funcionando tudo certinho, Obrigado pela ajuda!